# Use SSL on a multi tenant application with custom domains on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku, multi-tenant

I've been reading quite a lot about this and I have to admin I'm pretty confused.

So it's an app where every customer gets their own subdomain like xyz.example.com, and is able to use a custom domain by creating a CNAME that points to the subdomain version. So far so good.

The thing is that SSL needs to be activated. I understand that each customer needs to buy their own certificate for their custom domains, but that's where it gets blurry to me: how do I install the certificate? Would I simply use the Heroku API to upload them?

Basically I'm looking for a solution that would make it very easy for non-tech savvy users, potentially even providing the certificates myself as a reseller.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you can only have a single SSL per application, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain-ssl - it'll cost $20 per custom domain too.

You might have found something that will limit your ability to use Heroku in this case,

Comment: What would be my options then? The simplest I see right now is to get a wildcard certificate in order to enable SSL on the subdomains, and then ask my customers to use a service like Cloud Flare in order to put SSL on their domain. If I went back to a VPS on EC2 or else would I be able to put something together or will it just never happen?